# How do I display a cell in table view in a modal in iOS app?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a sale history table view controller that displays a list of orders that the cashier have entered from the previous menu. In the list of orders page, each cells display the order id and summary of orders.

I want to be able to tap on each cell(order) and display the entire order in either a new page or preferably a popup on the same page modally. However I am not sure which segue should I use and how do I go about doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe in iOS 8, you can use the push segue, and change the position attribute to from bottom and it will technically be a modal view. From there, just display another table view passing the id in the segue.